# Blur filter does not work in firefox

Tags: firefox, blur

I have a blur filter applied to the element `fullpage` which is not working in firefox. I tried also with an SVG filter, same result. I can not reproduce this problem in jsfiddle. And the real weird thing is, that if I have sent a mail via the contact form and click the menu-trigger after, then it is working.

Is anybody here who can see whats going wrong with it? Would be great, thanks.

[www.deintrainer.berlin](http://www.deintrainer.berlin/)
(to apply the class with the filter click on the menu trigger on the left)